# How to filter foriegnkey objects by current user in django admin page

Tags: django, django-models

This is the class CategoryAdmin:

```
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','desc','text']
    fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': ['name', 'desc', 'text']}),]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        if not obj.id:
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(CategoryAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=request.user)
```

Model class Product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", db_index=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=512)
    pub_dt = models.DateTimeField('date published', help_text="Please use the following format: <em>YYYY-MM-DD</em>.")
    cate = models.ForeignKey(Category, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Model class Category:

```
 class Category(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", db_index=True)
     name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
     desc = models.CharField(max_length=128)
     text = models.CharField(max_length=512)

     def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

When I add a Product and cate field is a dropdown list. How can I filter the item in dropdown list of the category by current user in subclass of ModelAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `formfield_for_foreignkey` ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey)).

In your case, it would be like that :

```
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name','category']
    fieldsets = [(None, {'fields': ['name', 'category']}),]

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    ...

def get_queryset(self, request):
    ...

def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "category":
        kwargs["queryset"] = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```